# Create keyboard shortcut to toggle Mac scroll direction

Tags: macos, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping, trackpad

I would like to be able to use a keyboard shortcut to toggle the vertical scroll direction on my Mac laptop. I already have an app called Karabiner installed which I use for a number of custom key mappings.

Is anyone familiar with Karabiner who knows how to edit the `private.xml` file to achieve this? (Ive edited `private.xml` before but only using `__KeyToKey__` and not to change an actual setting)

If not, does anyone know of another way that I could create a keyboard shortcut to toggle the scroll direction?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after getting some help elsewhere. If using the app Karabiner, click on the misc tab and click`Open private.xml`

Then add this to the private.xml file:

```
<vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_toggle_vertical_scroll_direction</name>
    <url type="shell">
      <![CDATA[    /Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Library/bin/karabiner toggle remap.reverse_vertical_scrolling    ]]>
    </url>
</vkopenurldef>

<item>
    <name>Reverse Scroll Direction with Shift_L+Shift_R+S</name>
    <identifier>private.reverse_scroll_direction</identifier>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
        KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SHELL_toggle_vertical_scroll_direction,
    </autogen>
</item>
```

The above code will switch the vertical scroll direction on your machine when you press "left shift + right shift + s"

Comment: Trying on macOS Sierra and Karabiner-Elements v 12.1.0 and can't find a way to do this

Comment: Unfortunately I also couldn't get this working with Karabiner v12.1.0....  :(
I'll update the answer if I find a work-around